# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Switch' with these attrs on iOS

Tags: tensorflow

On iOS I am trying to load a tensorflow graph which I have frozen by using `convert_variables_to_constants` however I am getting:

```
No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Switch' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]

     [[Node: dropout6/cond/Switch = Switch[T=DT_BOOL](Placeholder_2, Placeholder_2)]]
```

If then call `optimize_for_inference` on the graph and attempt to load, I get:

```
Input 0 of node dropout6/cond/dropout/random_uniform/max was passed bool from dropout6/cond/Switch:1 incompatible with expected INVALID.
```

This is what the `Placeholder_2` node looks like:

```
name: "Placeholder_2"
op: "Const"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_BOOL
  }
}
attr {
  key: "value"
  value {
    tensor {
      dtype: DT_BOOL
      tensor_shape {
      }
      bool_val: false
    }
  }
}
```

and this is what the Switch node looks like:

```
name: "dropout6/cond/Switch"
op: "Switch"
input: "Placeholder_2"
input: "Placeholder_2"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_BOOL
  }
}
```

and after optimizing we have:

```
name: "dropout6/cond/dropout/random_uniform/max"
op: "Const"
input: "dropout6/cond/Switch:1"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "value"
  value {
    tensor {
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      tensor_shape {
      }
      float_val: 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

This may be related to: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4790

Comment: It appears that the switch op for booleans is not supported on ios, maybe to avoid increasing the binary size too much. Is it possible to use a different graph which does not do switch on booleans?

Comment: I actually just filed this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5919.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround worked for me - change the following line in source code and rebuild.

```
#define TF_CALL_bool(m)
```

to

```
#define TF_CALL_bool(m) m(bool)
```

I found the directive [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.1.0-rc2/tensorflow/core/framework/register_types.h#L125).